# React Redux - Loading state too slow - how to solve it

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to create a loading state for my Redux but it looks to "slow" to get updated.

First action **fetchDB => setLoading: true => once over setLoading: false**

Second action **fetchCat => doesn't have the time to fire it that crashes**

Really simple:

set loading action:

```
export const setLoading = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    await dispatch({ type: SET_LOADING }); // no payload by default goes to true
  };
};
```

set loading reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_DB,
  SET_LOADING,
} from "../types"

const initalState = {
  db: [],
  loading: false,
}

export default (state = initalState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      
    // this like the other cases sets loading to FALSE
    case FETCH_DB:
      return {
        ...state,
        db: action.payload,
        current: null,
        loading: false,
      }

    case FETCH_CAT_FOOD:
      
      return {
        ...state,
        food: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }
    case FETCH_CAT_DESIGN:
      return {
        ...state,
        design: action.payload,
        loading: false,
      }

    case SET_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

then action I use that creates the problem:

```
    export const fetchCat =  kindof => {
    
      return async dispatch => {

      dispatch(setLoading()) // looks like that it doesn't get fired

   const response = await axios
          .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${kindof}`)
          .then(results => results.data)
    
        try {
          await dispatch({ type: `FETCH_CAT_${kindof}`, payload: response })
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("await error", error)
        }
      }
    }
```

and then the file (a custom component) that creates the problem.
It crashes cause `categories.map` is undefined.
It doesn't find loading: true so the loader doesn't stop.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react"

import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap"

import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux"

import CatItem from "./CatItem" // custom component

import { fetchCat, setLoading } from "../../../store/actions/appActions"

const MapCat = ({ kindof, loading, categories }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCat(kindof)) // gives the category I want to fetch
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [categories])


  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <Spinner animation="border" role="status">
        <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </Spinner>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div>
          {categories.map(item => (
            <CatItem item={item} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, kindof) =>
  ({
    loading: state.appDb.loading,
    categories: state.appDb[kindof],
  })

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCat, setLoading })(MapCat)
```

I think that it is supposed to work like this:

**loading: false (by default) => true => time to fetch => false**

But doesn't look like working. Any idea?

Comment: Create a separate `loading` state for each of the different types of fetches. Make use of [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) and move them to their own sub-reducers.

Comment: I thought about it but then it's too complicated, and less flexible so I'm trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly `setLoading` needs to return a plain object with `type` and payload

```js
export const setLoading = () => ({ type: SET_LOADING });
```

2. In `fetchCat` the `then` is not required. Also async await for dispatch is not required.

```js
export const fetchCat = (kindof) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setLoading()); //<---this should now be ok.

    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/categories/${kindof}`)
    //   .then((results) => results.data); //<----- not required as you are using await

    try {
      dispatch({ type: `FETCH_CAT_${kindof}`, payload: response.data }); //<--- use response.data ...also async/await for dispatch is not rquired.
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("await error", error);
    }
  };
};
```

3. The 2nd arg of mapStateToProps is ownProps [which is an object](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional)

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) =>
  ({
    loading: state.appDb.loading,
    categories: state.appDb[ownProps.kindof],
  })
```

Comment: thanks a lot! you clarified me a lot of thinks! Now I think that the problem is that `categories` doesn't get upadated cause if I log it is always undefined, despite the DevTools are showing me they fetched everything, if I log `categories` I get always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a bit different way of calling dispatch. Let me list them out

```
    dispatch(fetchCat(kindof)) // gives the category I want to fetch
```

```
    await dispatch({ type: `FETCH_CAT_${kindof}`, payload: response })
```

You can see, `await` or not basically is the way you use `async` operation. However dispatch takes `type` and `payload` to function, which means you have to make sure what you send to dispatch is with the right object. Of course `Redux` does accept custom format via plugins, so maybe if you throw it a `async` as input, the reducer might understand it as well?

Please double check each dispatch first, for example, write a function that only dispatch one type of action. Only after you make each call working, don't move to assemble them together into a bundled call.

Comment: thanks but I think the problem is different, at least now. I mean it looks like not updating `categories` and map them

Comment: that's fine, as long as. you know which dispatch isn't working, that'll help you solve the final puzzle :)